# How to install Ubuntu on Acer Swift X

Tags: boot, live-usb, laptop, acer, 22.10

I'm trying to install Ubuntu on a brand-new Acer Swift X SFX14-42G-R607.  The liveUSB doesn't run the installation environment, failing with these messages (I added 'nosplash' and removed 'quiet'):

**[time] = a number with the clock time; I typed this out manually**

- This is ubuntu-22.10-live-server-amd64.iso.  ubuntu-22.10-desktop-amd64.iso is similar.

```
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.0.1 uses VM inv eng 7 on hub 0
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.1.1 uses VM inv eng 8 on hub 0
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.2.1 uses VM inv eng 9 on hub 0
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring comp_1.3.1 uses VM inv eng 10 on hub 0
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring kiq_2.1.0 uses VM inv eng 11 on hub 0
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring sdma0 uses VM inv eng 0 on hub 1
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_dec uses VM inv eng 1 on hub 1
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc0 uses VM inv eng 4 on hub 1
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring vcn_enc1 uses VM inv eng 5 on hub 1
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: amdgpu: ring jpeg_dec uses VM inv eng 6 on hub 1
[time] [drm] Initialized amdgpu 3.47.0 20150101 for 0000:04:00.0 on minor 0
[time] fbcon: amdgpudrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[time] [drm] DSC precompute is not needed
[time] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
[time] amdgpu 0000:04:00.0: [drm] fb0: amdgpudrmfb frame buffer device
[time] acpi AMDI0010:03: Already enumerated
[time] usb1-2: reset high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Begin: Loading essential drivers ... [time] raid6: avx2x4  gen() 20742 MB/s
[time] raid6: avx2x2  gen() 19179 MB/s
[time] raid6: avx2x1  gen() 13288 MB/s
[time] raid6: using algorithm avx2x4 gen() 20742 MB/s
[time] raid6: .... xor() 3880 MB/s, rmw enabled
[time] raid6: using avx2x2 recovery algorithm
[time] xor: automatically using best checksumming function   avx
[time] async_tx: api initialized (async)
done.
Begin: Running /scripts/init-premount ... done.
Begin: Mounting root file system ... Begin: Running /scripts/nfs-top ... done.
Begin: Running /scripts/nfs-premount ... done.
<< hangs forever >>
<< If I remove the usb, I get: [time] usb 1-2: USB disconnect, device number 2 >>
```

I tried Ubuntu Mini, but it doesn't recognize the wifi adapter to download packages.  I have disabled SecureBoot and tried 'nomodeset' (no effect).  I'd be happy to just wipe the drive and install a terminal-only setup at this point.

Note: Not sure this is significant, but in experimenting with other distro liveUSBs (they similarly fail), I see this message onstartup: 'nouveau 0000:01:00.0: unknown chipset (b77000a1)'.

P.S. 'Similar questions' don't have the same issue.

Comment: Servers do not have desktops. You want to install an ISO of Ubuntu Desktop not server if you want a GUI by default.

Comment: By 'run the desktop', I really meant 'run the installation environment', which Ubuntu Desktop does via the live desktop (edited above).  Here I'm trying Ubuntu Server, hoping to avoid video card issues as a factor.  I just want to wipe the drive and install a terminal at this point.

Answer (score 0):

This "installer is stuck at 'Triggering uevents...'" is all over the place, most with no good answers.

I'm not entirely sure I fully understand why the Ubuntu liveUSB was hanging, but using Rufus to make the liveUSB from the Win11 installation fixed it.  I used `oobe\bypassnro` to avoid Win11 connecting to the internet (use Shift + F10 to open a cmd.exe console):  https://www.windowscentral.com/how-set-windows-11-without-microsoft-account

Relatedly, my preference of the Manjaro liveUSB was hanging because it searches for the usb by label "MANJARO_KDE_".  If you burn the liveUSB with unetbootin or Rufus, you may have a different label on the usb.  Also, the unique partition structure will be different than what it's expecting.  Manjaro seems to prefer using `dd` to make the liveUSB, as I did:
`sudo dd status=progress if=manjaro-kde-22.0.5-230316-linux61.iso of=/dev/sde bs=1M`

Some diagnostic steps that helped:

- At the grub menu, press 'e' to modify the linux kernel options: `loglevel=7`, `nosplash`, and removing `quiet` will let you see the what's going on during startup.
- When I managed to install ubuntu after much windows partition trial and error, `lsblk` helps identify the usb port/stick details.
- Although this wasn't MY solution: A lot of sources say to use `nomodeset`, to avoid video driver crashes on startup.  It seems you want to put this as early as possible in the kernel options (after 'x86_64').
- Although this wasn't MY solution: If you must manually mount the usb from grub, this post describes making the symlinks that help the installer: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=77815

Comment: Rufus is the most reliable option for making a Live Media USB.